# How to bundle images resources of React Native in Android?

Tags: android, image, resources, bundle, react-native

I use

```
react-native bundle --entry-file "index.android.js" --platform "android" --bundle-output "./assets/index.android.bundle" --verbose
```

to package the JS code bundle and put it into assets, it works but the local Image resources can't be displayed, the local image resources located in `./App/Img/` folder, and be used in:

```
const icon1 = require('./App/Img/slider.png');
```

How can I bundle this resource files too so that I can generate a single running apk.

Comment: Did u manage to get this working ?

Comment: yes, see the answer blew.

Answer (score 3):

I use the **bundle** command to bundle resources into android res/ folder:

```
    echo "START bundle for android normal resources release"
    react-native bundle \
    --platform android \
    --entry-file index.android.js \
    --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
    --assets-dest  android/app/src/main/res/ \
    --dev false
```

then build with gradlew:

```
./gradlew installRelease
```

Comment: I presume this will not work with iOS. Any cross-platform solution?