# PNG images from URL not displaying in react native android 4.4.2

Tags: react-native

i am getting some PNG images from server. all of the images display perfectly in emulator which is android 8.0 but faild to display on the android 4.4.2 device. 
i used the link below but it did'nt help me.

[React-native: Images not showing in android device; but shows perfectly in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385129/react-native-images-not-showing-in-android-device-but-shows-perfectly-in-emula)

here are some of my codes:

```
<Avatar
          rounded
          source={{uri:"https://banner2.kisspng.com/20171201/245/nature-png-clipart-5a2223a1e22f61.3399622815121867859265.jpg"}}
          containerStyle={{ marginLeft: 12, marginRight: 20}}
        />
```

using react native elements.
i also use react native snap carousel and Image component. but in none of them image will not display in android 4 on the device

Comment: Can you provide some code, or sample of how you are doing it?

Comment: <Avatar
              rounded
              source={{uri:"https://banner2.kisspng.com/20171201/245/nature-png-clipart-5a2223a1e22f61.3399622815121867859265.jpg"}}
              // source={{ uri: this.state.category[i].flag }}
              containerStyle={{ marginLeft: 12, marginRight: 20}}
              
            />

Comment: give it a `height` and a `width` in the style and see if it works

Comment: i gave it . not working. as i said it displays on emulator but not on device. there might be a problem with android version

Comment: instead of using `Avatar` can you swap with `Image` from RN and see if it displays the image?

Comment: i tried . not displaying. avatar and react native snap carousel both using Image component.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to debug it. Have you tried to bundle the image locally? It might be something with the bundler. FWIW Android 4 isn't supported anymore so I'm not sure how much you're going to gain out of this

Comment: png images locally displays perfectly on the device and emulator. the problem is that i want to get some images from server and it is not showing them

Comment: If you attach a remote debugger, you might be able to see what the error is. Is the phone connected to the internet?

Comment: yes it is connected

Comment: when i want to catch error on the onError prop the whole application hangs . though i cant find out where the problem is