# React Native: uri image not showing on android but displays on the iOS Simulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a react-native app. I am fetching some images from an API and displaying them as a flat-list. The problem is that these images show perfectly on the ***iOS*** Simulator but do not display on the ***Android*** emulator. I have set the widths and heights to the images but the issue remains the same.
Here is the code below
**Component**

```js
 <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{
            uri: image,
          }}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
```

**Styles**

```js
container__image: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
```

The `image` in front of the `uri` is a prop that contains the `http` address of the image.

Answer (score 3):

I don't rely on the `Android` emulator regarding images from URL, especially if those are coming from APIs. Hardcoded URLs, in general, are working fine.

However, I've noticed the `iOS` simulator regarding that aspect gives similar results to an `iPhone`. It's not the case for `Android`. While fetching images from APIs, storing it on the phone in `store` logic/`AsyncStorage` I've noticed the real `Android` device shows way more pictures than the `Android` emulator. It took me such a long time to find out why *images do not work on Android, but work on iOS* with lots of topics on Stack Overflow. Apparently, they did work, but on real device... Yes, during debugging I've checked `http` & `https`. Those images were served over `https`. I've had also `width` and `height` set.

A bit frustrating, but I'm quite curious if there are more folks experienced that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but when I quit the app in the emulator and reopened it, it was fine, although it's not the best solution, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it seems to be a problem that arises because `Android` does not allow `http`.

Please build a new `Android` after changing `Android` settings as follows.

- android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> // you add this
...
</application>
```

Comment: Sorry I misspelled its `https`

Comment: @AliRaza Can you share the image path for the test?

Comment: I have added your solution to my file as well but its not working

Comment: https://digidrip-dev.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/1641987422138-image.png

Comment: It is working for me using the below code:
`import React from 'react';
import {View, Image} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  let image = 'https://digidrip-dev.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/1641987422138-image.png'
  return(
    <View>
    <Image
      style={{ width: '100%', height: 200, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
      source={{
        uri: image,
      }}
      resizeMode="contain"
    />
    </View>
  )}`

Comment: I have hardcoded these values but it works fine on the ios but not on the android emulator its displays nothing

Comment: @AliRaza threre no problem. here is example https://snack.expo.dev/U3npZ0Sj1H

Comment: Ok, what should I do then? I have updated the .xml file but its not working.

Comment: The problem is it's working fine on IOS but not on android.

Comment: @AliRaza This question is completely different from the one you asked. End it and post a new one.

Comment: My image component is in a `flatlist`

Comment: @AliRaza Look at android on the link I shared. There's no problem at all.

Comment: @AliRaza threre no problem. here is use flatlist example  https://snack.expo.dev/x8d6rQV7U

Comment: @aliRaza. i have the same problem. no idea, just misery loves company. I hard code url on <image> with 100px width height. works fine on ios sim, fails on android sim. RN 0.66.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem?
I have the same problem and I fixed it by

1. close android simulator
2. `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
3. wipe data in android studio device manager

and run `react-native start --reset-cache && react-native run-android`

Comment: still didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving **direct link** in the uri within quotes (single or double).This might work in **android** and your resizemode will also have to come inside the styles.

```js
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
          }}
        />
```

Comment: I tried that. does not work on android sim. works on ios sim. set width:100 height:100. i also tried resize mode cover/contain. no image shows.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the **Storage Permission**.

Check the app details on the phone and give storage permission to the app

Answer (score 0):

Some folks who are reaching here, this might work for them.

There might be an issue with prop you are providing:

For both Android and iOS to work the; prop should be "uri"
For only iOS prop is "url". This will not load images on android, even it will not start network request.